# Public transportation in Cangas

Tags: public-transport, spain

Is there any route map of public transportation around Cangas, Pontevedra. Particularly are there any buses going west from the town?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the website of Cangas there are two bus companies serving the town, Monbus and Cerqueiro. The latter runs two lines going west, [L7 to Donon](http://www.autobusescerqueiro.es/descargas.aspx?Grupo=5) and [L8 to Vilanova](http://www.autobusescerqueiro.es/descargas.aspx?Grupo=6). Each line is depicted on its own map, but I did not find a single map that would cover them all.